# how do i extract value inside quotes using regex python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My text is

```
my_text = '"posted_data":"2e54eba66f8f2881c8e78be8342428xd","isropa":false,"rx":"NO","readal":"false"'
```

I am trying to extract value of `posted_data` which is `2e54eba66f8f2881c8e78be8342428xd`

My code :

```
extract_posted_data = re.search(r'(\"posted_data\": \")(\w*)', my_text)
print (extract_posted_data)
```

and it prints None

Thank you

Comment: Which is demonstrable via [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LJbRLU/1). Although this data doesn't require a regex to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your original code has an additional space. It should be:

```
extract_posted_data = re.search(r'(\"posted_data\":\")(\w*)', my_text)
```

And in fact, `'\'` is unnecessary here. Just:

```
extract_posted_data = re.search(r'("posted_data":")(\w*)', my_text)
```

Then:

```
extract_posted_data.group(2)
```

is what you want.

```
>>> my_text = '"posted_data":"2e54eba66f8f2881c8e78be8342428xd","isropa":false,"rx":"NO","readal":"false"'
>>> extract_posted_data = re.search(r'("posted_data":")(\w*)', my_text)   
>>> extract_posted_data.group(2)
'2e54eba66f8f2881c8e78be8342428xd'
```

Comment: print (extract_posted_data)
None

Comment: @elrichbachman This is impossible. I copy the answer to Python, the result is pasted.

Comment: yeah you're right i am sorry for that i did mistake , i am getting result but i need to only extract value 2e54eba66f8f2881c8e78be8342428xd 
i tried print (extract_posted_data[1]) but it gives me TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 3):

This particular example doesn't seem like it needs regular expressions at all.

```
>>> my_text
'"posted_data":"2e54eba66f8f2881c8e78be8342428xd","isropa":false,"rx":"NO","readal":"false"'
>>> import json
>>> result = json.loads('{%s}' % my_text)
>>> result
{'posted_data': '2e54eba66f8f2881c8e78be8342428xd', 'isropa': False, 'rx': 'NO', 'readal': 'false'}
>>> result['posted_data']
'2e54eba66f8f2881c8e78be8342428xd'
```

With `BeautifulSoup`:

```
>>> import json
... 
... from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
... 
... soup = BeautifulSoup('<script type="text/javascript"> "posted_data":"2738273283723hjasda" </script>')
... 
... result = json.loads('{%s}' % soup.script.text)
>>> result
{'posted_data': '2738273283723hjasda'}
>>> result['posted_data']
'2738273283723hjasda'
```

Comment: the data is inside html its like this my_text = '<script type="text/javascript"> "posted_data":"2738273283723hjasda" </script>'

Comment: @elrichbachman You shouldn't be parsing HTML with regular expressions to begin with. This method will still work with something like `BeautifulSoup` though, see edit. Also, there may be a way to send that request yourself and get that JSON response by itself (what's the url?).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your regex to use lookarounds, as follows:

```
my_text = '"posted_data":"2e54eba66f8f2881c8e78be8342428xd","isropa":false,"rx":"NO","readal":"false"'
extract_posted_data = re.search(r'(?<="posted_data":")\w*(?=")', my_text)
print (extract_posted_data[0])
```

Prints  `2e54eba66f8f2881c8e78be8342428xd`

Also `re.search()` returns a Match object, so to get the first match (the only match) you get index 0 of the match:

Answer (score 1):

as others have mentioned json would be a better tool for this data but you can also use this regex (I added a \s* in case in the future there are spaces in between):

regex: `"posted_data":\s*"(?P<posted_data>[^"]+)"`

```
import re

my_text = '"posted_data":"2e54eba66f8f2881c8e78be8342428xd","isropa":false,"rx":"NO","readal":"false"'
m = re.search(r'"posted_data":\s*"(?P<posted_data>[^"]+)"', my_text)
if m:
    print(m.group('posted_data'))
```